# How to do the mapping for filtering

Tags: html, spring-boot, mapping

I am using spring boot and I am trying to filter a book list using author, title, description and publishing date however I am not able to do the mapping in the right way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZjSX.png)

I am so new to this so could you correct me?
here is the mapping part in my controller:

```
/*
@GetMapping(value = "/filter", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<Book> filterBooks(@RequestParam(name = "author", required = true) String author,
                              @RequestParam(name = "title", required = true) String title,
                              @RequestParam(name = "description", required = true) String desc,
                              @RequestParam(name = "publishedDate", required = true) String publishedDate) {
    return bookService.filterBooks(author, title, desc, publishedDate);
}*/

@GetMapping(value = "/filter", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String filterBooks (Model model) {
    public List<Book> filterBooks (@RequestParam(name = "author", required = true) String author,
            @RequestParam(name = "title", required = true) String title,
            @RequestParam(name = "description", required = true) String desc,
            @RequestParam(name = "publishedDate", required = true) String publishedDate){
        model.addAttribute("filterBooks", filterBooks);
        // return bookService.filterBooks(author, title, desc, publishedDate);
        return"filter";
    }
}
```

Here is my filter.html file: https://pastebin.com/87rFZj9Z

And here is the filtering functiong in the book service implementation file:

```
    public List<Book> filterBooks(String author, String title, String description, String publishedDate) {
    List<Book> filteredBooks = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(books)) {
        filteredBooks.addAll(books.stream()
                .filter(book -> filterByAuthor(book, author) && filterByTitle(book, title)
                        && filterByDesc(book, description) && filterByPublishDate(book, publishedDate))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
    return filteredBooks;
}

private boolean filterByAuthor(Book book, String author) {
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(author) ? Boolean.TRUE : book.getAuthor().equalsIgnoreCase(author);
}

private boolean filterByTitle(Book book, String title) {
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(title) ? Boolean.TRUE : book.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title);
}

private boolean filterByDesc(Book book, String description) {
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(description) ? Boolean.TRUE : book.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase(description);
}

private boolean filterByPublishDate(Book book, String publishDate) {
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(publishDate) ? Boolean.TRUE : book.getPublish_date().equalsIgnoreCase(publishDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi example code block RestController Spring boot

```
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("/example")
  public class BooksController {

  @GetMapping(value = "/filter", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public String filterBooks (@ModelAtribute("model") Model model , @RequestParam(name = "author", required = true) String 
        author,
        @RequestParam(name = "title", required = true) String title,
        @RequestParam(name = "description", required = true) String description,
        @RequestParam(name = "publishedDate", required = true) String publishedDate){
    model.addAttribute("filterBooks", filterBooks);
    // return bookService.filterBooks(author, title, description, publishedDate);
    return"filter";
    }
 }
```

Comment: It is not fixing the problem

Comment: what the problem your ?

Comment: I am dont understand your problem

Comment: 2021-05-19 10:38:53.740  WARN 6254 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'author' for method parameter type String is not present]

Comment: I added         List<Book> filterBooks = bookService.filterBooks(author, title, description, publishedDate);

Comment: Your added filterBooks working code blocks ?

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'author' for method parameter type String is not present]

Comment: Inas editing answer and adde ModelAtriute please check

Comment: Add ModelAttribute dependency your not dependency pom.xml

Comment: please delete RequestParam required=true

Comment: Thanks Inas not problem